# GDAL pre-allocates raster file

Tags: gdal

I am using GDAL 2.01 SWIG in C# to create an imagine file.  When I call Create it pre-allocates the entire file, so if I am writing a 80GB file it I have to wait for it to allocate the 80GB file before I can begin writing to it.

Is there a way to create the 'empty' raster and then fill it as needed?

```
OSGeo.GDAL.Driver driver = OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.GetDriverByName("HFA");
OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset dataset = driver.Create("C:\\Test.img", 172032, 98304, 1, OSGeo.GDAL.DataType.GDT_Float32, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in the code, this is not possible with the HFA driver (with the GTiff driver, you wouldn't have this issue). On Linux, creation of the whole file is instantaneous as the file is created in a sparse way, but on Windows, it requires extra code to enable sparse mode from what I can see in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, and this is not currently implemented.

So short answer is: no

Answer (score 1):

Note: I've just committed improvements in GDAL trunk that should solve that performance issue :

- https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/34567
- https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/34570